# Any Open Source Linux Distributed Storage Options Which be Deployed inside Rented KVM VPSes Without Additional Virtual Disks?

Tags: storage, distributed-filesystems

I am trying to figure out a scalable *and* HA solution for storing *live data under production workloads like DBs, web contents, etc.*. Which can be installed and setup on *standard rented Linux KVM VPSes. Which only have the virtual disk which it's boots off of.*

Tried looking at CephFS, requires *block level storage* cause it's "sits on top of the OBJ Ceph clustering".

As well as GlusterFS but it doesn't support *live structured data like databases* and I don't feels comfortable to make the setup harder and more complicated. By having to HA and clustering DBs separately (not to mention increasing costs further).

XteremeFS was *sorta* on the right set of tracks when I checked it out for decent bit. Except it's *only does RAID0* at the moment. So forget about scaling and never mind HAing that...

In short are there *real* options that doesn't requires physical or block level storage devices *nor* is complicated to install and set up? Or otherwise "to make it all work together?".

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You need dedicated servers for this. VPSes will not do.

Comment: I understand if it not simply possible to RAIN Array a couple of KVM VPSes together since it would requires access to the underlying hardware. But I still wanted to inquire if this would be possible to assist with handling services with my medical conditions in mind. Most service providers probably have Push Notifications or something that they can wake up for that 3AM downtime, while I can't because of my conditions. Obviously as I was asking this question, outsourcing this is out of my budgets compared to spinning up a couple of KVM VMs.